# A SciFi / Paranormal tv series from 10+ years ago

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a SciFi/Paranormal thriller kind of tv-series with a man that had a special gift. I remember some vague details, like glowing spiders as one of the problems he needed to solve in an episode.

Some more general memories: the main character always needed some kind of antidote or injections from some sinister person. Also, the intro sequence contained lots of biology closeups, like cells mutating or similar, with lots of glowing yellow highlights (but I don't know how much I got influenced by House's intro).

Sorry to be so vague - it's from when I was a child and I really don't remember much, except that I was somehow strangely attracted to it.

It very probably is aired before the year 2000.

Comment: When you say "gift" do you mean supernatural power (magic, lightning bolts, etc), or something more conventional, like charm and cleverness?

Comment: Yes, some kind of paranormal power, he could see or sense certain things, like those radio-active like spiders or so. Sorry, it's very vague :)

Comment: He did not have powers like lightning bolts and superstrength etc.

Comment: The problem is that this sounds like half the paranormal dramas of the time. You might have to find some more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some elements of this remind me of the late-90's/early-00's show *Strange World*.  The main character in that show had to get a treatment from a shadowy organization for his aplastic anemia, which came from a shadowy woman who also used his dependence on the treatment to get him to work against his superiors.  You can see the opening [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCIcgHLHQAg), it contains many biological references/elements.

However, I can't recall or find any details on one of the cases of the week having glowing spiders.  Nor do I think he had any supernatural powers.

Comment: Wow!!!! That's it indeed! That's the intro! Thanks a thousand times!!! Maybe there weren't supernatural powers? Anyway, this is it, so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't remember the opening, but this sounds like the SciFi series [*The Invisible Man*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Man_%282000_TV_series%29).  He had a gland implanted in him that let him become invisible, but he couldn't use it for but so long at a time.  He had a tattoo, I think it was a snake, with lines drawn between sections so it was, essentially, a meter to let him know how much time he had left to use his invisibility.

He had to get regular injections to help him and if he went over the line from staying invisible too long, he had to get medical attention immediately.

His brother made him invisible and a secret department in the government took over.  Their official attachment to one section or another changed from time to time, depending on funding.  While the person who gave him the injections wasn't sinister (and there was some romantic/sexual tension with him and the woman doctor who monitored him), the guy running the department was not exactly someone you'd trust.

I'm not sure if this is it, since some of what you say matches, but other stuff doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, that's not him. Although I see indeed a lot of stuff that matches the series, but no.

Comment: Okay -- but now I'm interested in what the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say this is the Invisible Man which matches the injections except you've already turned that one down. So I'll go with the similar in some ways show of Jake 2.0. In this show the main character gets nanobots into his blood much like in The Invisible man by a lab accident/ holdup. He is then used by the NSA as an agent and sent on missions. The nanobots give him various abilities such as control over electronics, super strength, super eyesight etc. I don't remember a specific episode with spiders that glowed but I believe the nanobots looked like spiders. It also has a biology closeup in the intro. Here's a link to the intro clip on youtube Jake 2.0

Comment: Wow, great answer, but no, it's not him. :S. The character certainly has no superstrength and more like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the show you are refering to. I also loved the show when it was airing. I am not sure of the original name but it seems to be I-Man. A gland of an animal was implanted and he needed injections to maintain his madness. The "snake" tatoo was also a monitor that each section changed from green to red and he needed to have the injection before he lost total control of himself.

http://youtu.be/T0FNLcsfMMk

Comment: Hi, As seen in the marked answer, I already found the show, and it was not this, I am sorry.